# Como hacer para que una peticion $http.get se complete antes que otra en angularjs

Tags: angularjs, web, http, callback, http-get

tengo un problema con los servicios en angular y es que estoy llamando una funcion con peticion $http.get dentro de un servicio que tambien hace peticion $http.get.

Este es mi codigo cuando pulso consultar, si ven dentro de el hay una funcion llamada **searchDeuda()** que es la que quiero que se finalice primero. Como se hace eso en Angular?

```
    function consultar(cuenta) {
               //Funcion que tambien hace una peticion $http 
                    searchDeuda();

                var config = {
                    params: {
                        cuentaNro: $scope.cuenta,
                        username: $scope.username
                    }
                };

                apiService.get('api/cuentasAsociadas/consultar/', config,
                loadCompleted,
                loadFailed);
            }

function loadCompleted(result) {

        if ($scope.conDeuda == true) {
            $location.path('/arregloPago').replace();
        } else {
            notificationService.displayDialog("Aviso", 'Cuenta no posee Deudas', "OK");
        }
    }
}



    function loadFailed(response) {
        //notificationService.showConfirm('Aviso!!!', response.data, 'OK');
        notificationService.showConfirm(this, 'Aviso!!!', response.data, 'AGREGAR CUENTA', 'OK')
                .then(function () {
                    $location.path('/cuentasAsociadas/agregarCuenta').replace();
                }, function () {

                });
    }
```

//Funcion que esta dentro de la peticion consultar

```
function searchDeuda() {
        var config = {
            params: {
                CuentaNro: $scope.cuenta
            }
        };            

        apiService.get('api/ArregloPago/Deuda/', config,
        deudasLoadCompleted,
        deudasLoadFailed);
    } 



function deudasLoadCompleted(result) {
        if (result.data == 'Cuenta no posee Deudas') {
            $scope.conDeuda = false;
        } else {
            $scope.conDeuda = true;
        }
    }



  function deudasLoadFailed(response) {
        notificationService.displayError('Error al buscar deuda');
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo puede lograr utilizando un callback en `searchDedua`.

Edita `searchDeuda` para que acepta una función que se ejecutara cuando haya obtenido el resultado:

```
function searchDeuda(callback) {
        var config = {
            params: {
                CuentaNro: $scope.cuenta
            }
        };            

        apiService.get('api/ArregloPago/Deuda/', config,function(response){
            deudasLoadCompleted(response);
            callback(response);
        },deudasLoadFailed);
 }
```

Entonces cuando vayas a consultar, le envias el callback a searchDeuda, en este caso desde consultar:

```
function consultar(cuenta) {

   // definimos el metodo
    searchDeuda(function(response){

        // cuando recibas la respuesta de searchDeuda,
        // se ejecutara esta funcion

        var config = {
            params: {
                cuentaNro: $scope.cuenta,
                username: $scope.username
            }
        };

        apiService.get('api/cuentasAsociadas/consultar/', config,
        loadCompleted,
        loadFailed);

    });
}
```

Asi entonces cuando searchDeuda obtenga el resultado, es cuando `apiService.get('api/cuentasAsociadas/consultar/')` se ejecutara.

Comment: OK, voy a implementarlo ahorita. Gracias de antemano Nuevamente

Comment: Me funciono!!! Gracias Einer Santana, cuando lo probe olvide pasarle como parametro una funcion a searchDeuda